# Change/Customize Preference Screen Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, android-alertdialog, android-preferences

I've created a preference screen with androidx preference library. The problem is when I click the EditTextPreference, the alert dialog is completely white. I guess it's because I've defined primary text color and secondary text color in my app theme. So how can I apply a custom theme for the preference alert dialog? here's how the dialog looks like right now when I tap the EditTextPreference:

[image]

**Style.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/layoutBG</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/layoutMainBG</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textSecondaryLight</item>
</style>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">@color/textBlue</color>
    <color name="textPrimaryLight">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="textSecondaryLight">#D7D7D7</color>
    <color name="charging">#388e3c</color>
    <color name="textBlue">#70b3c6</color>
    <color name="layoutBG">#171717</color>
    <color name="layoutMainBG">#0d0d0d</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding these two lines in my AppTheme

```xml
        <item name="colorBackgroundFloating">@color/layoutBG</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/textPrimaryLight</item>
```

So my new AppTheme looks like this

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/layoutBG</item>
        <item name="backgroundColor">@color/layoutMainBG</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/textPrimaryLight</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textSecondaryLight</item>
        <item name="colorBackgroundFloating">@color/layoutBG</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/textPrimaryLight</item>
    </style>
```